# How can I go about making a many2many relationship to self in golang gorm?

Tags: go, psql, go-gorm

I have a psql Database, and I am using the gorm library as well as the pq driver, as you see there is a many to many relationship for related products, however this throws out the error  `pq: column "product_id" specified more than once` is there a way to set an alias or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
type Product struct {
    Id          int64      `json:"_id"`
    Price       float32    `json:"price"`
    Name        string     `sql:"size:255" json:"name"`
    Description string     `json:"description"`
    Material    string     `json:"material"`
    Color       string     `json:"color"`
    ColorId     int64      `json:"colorId"`
    Categories  []Category `gorm:"many2many:product_categories;" json:"categories"`
    Images      []Image    `json:"images"`
    Tags        []Tag      `gorm:"many2many:product_tags;" json:"tags"`
    Main        bool       `json:"main"`
    Available   bool       `json:"available"`
    Slug        string     `json:"slug"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time  `json:"createdAt"`
    Related     []Product  `gorm:"many2many:related_products;" json:"related"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found  the solution of self-referencing many2many relationship. :D

```
type User struct {
    Id int64
    Related     []Product  `gorm:"foreignkey:product_id;associationforeignkey:related_product_id;many2many:related_products;" json:"related"`        
}
```

Comment: I think you meant "type Product struct { ..."
However I tried this solution, but when I call "db.Save(&myProduct)" nothing will be added to related_products
and related_products will have only one column named product_id which doesn't seem correct, where is related_product_id?!

Comment: This may have worked at some point in the past but it does not work with any recent version. Please see this pull request for a possible solution that has been tested to work with the latest version: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/pull/1709

Answer (score 1):

Kinda old post but fortunately gorm have added lately this feature (reference: [here](http://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Self-Referencing)).

In your case should be like this:

```
type Product struct {
  Id          int64      `json:"_id"`
  .
  .
  .
  Related     []Product `gorm:"many2many:related_products;association_jointable_foreignkey:related_id"`
}
```